# Wordpress site down on AWS after changing to elastic IP

Tags: php, wordpress, amazon-ec2, blogs, elastic-ip

My wordpress site was working perfectly through internal ec2 public ip just then i changed to elactic ip in order to point it to a DNS. Currently its down, first page comes up and when i try to customize the site its not showing proper content and every things looks down. Pasting screenshot.

[image: Screenshot of wordpress site]

I have done following steps to resole this issue from this site: 
https://wordpress.org/support/article/changing-the-site-url/

1. made changes in wp-config.php

   define('WP_HOME','http://yoursite.com'); 
   define('WP_SITEURL','http://yoursite.com');
2. Edit functions.php #

   http://example.com' );
   update_option( 'home', 'http://example.com' );
3. edit wp-config.php

   define('RELOCATE',true);

Not sure how to access database and make changes to that, so stuck in this step.

Please help if you have any other technique to resolve this issue.
I have multiple blog post in my site which i am developing, don't know how to transfer to another location if this failing.

Thanks,
Harish

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question should be posted on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: closing this questions for now, couldn't find a resolution.